# WordPress Delete Users from backend doesn't work

Tags: posts, users, customization

When I delete user & that user content from backend, user was deleted successfully but wordpress doesn't delete that user posts & comments even I select "**Delete all content**" radio button. Does anyone know why? I know how to delete user data using user delete action but wordpress backend user already has "delete user & delete user content", so I don't need to code for that, I think.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it takes a while then gives a white screen of death or an error about time limits? PHP can only do so many things in a single request, it's on a timer, if your user has a lot of content to delete then it may not finish deleting it before it runs out of time

Comment: I just created only one post and it can't be executing time. And also, I tested in local and increased that already.

Comment: what exactly happens? You mentioned it doesn't work, but you never described what happens. Also that confirm deletion button isn't styled like a normal WP install, is this a custom plugin? What do your PHP error logs say?

Comment: I have already mentioned on my question. It is not php errors. user was deleted successfully but it doesn't delete that user created posts and comments. Deleted user posts and comments are still in database

Comment: is this the standard WP core user deletion interface? Your Admin UI style does not look like standard WordPress, is that a custom colour scheme? Are you sure there are no warnings or notices in your PHP error log file? Have you verified this is not caused by your theme or a plugin by deactivating them all and trying again, turning them on 1 by 1 to see which one causes the problem? Can you confirm that the content that isn't deleted is a normal standard WP post?